# Is it possible to initialize properties at the beginning of a class?

Tags: swift

I am writing my project and wondered.
When I read literature or watch videos, I see that this is bad practice. Why? Is this bad for the system?

What is the difference between this

```swift
class SomeClass {
    var someView = SomeView()
    var someViewModel = SomeViewModel() 
// ...
}
```

and this

```swift
class SomeClass {
    var someView: SomeView! 
    var someViewModel: SomeViewModel?
// ...
}
```

How to get used to it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize all instance properties somehow. And you have to do it right up front, either in the declaration line or in your `init` method.

But what if you don't actually have the initial value until later, like in `viewDidLoad`? Then it is silly to supply a real heavyweight value only to replace it later:

```
var v = MyView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.v = // get _real_ MyView and assign it in place of that
}
```

Instead, we use an Optional to mark the fact that we have no value yet; until we obtain and assign one, it will be `nil`:

```
var v : MyView? // means it is initially `nil`
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.v = // get _real_ MyView and assign it to our property
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the first way (which is called a "default property value", by the way), and in fact, often times it's preferable. But of course, the devil is in the details:

1. How would the initialization of a `SomeViewModel` work? Without acess the initializer parameters of `SomeClass`, you're stuck with only being able to construct an instance from a parameter-less init, like `SomeViewModel()`. What exactly could that do? Suppose it was a person view model, and you had `PersonViewModel()`. What person? Whats their name? What will this default value do at all?
2. It's not a great pattern if it requires overwriting the default value with some other value in the initializer
3. It initializes the value up-front, where sometimes a lazy or computed value might be more appropriate.